# Is there a difference between DictionarySectionHandler and NameValueSectionHandler?

Tags: c#, .net, configuration, app-config, configsection

In .NET, we can create custom configuration sections using the [`<configSections>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa903350(v=vs.71).aspx) element, like so:

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="dictionarySample"
             type="System.Configuration.DictionarySectionHandler"/>
    <section name="nameValueSample"
             type="System.Configuration.NameValueSectionHandler" />
  </configSections>
  <dictionarySample>
    <add key="key1" 
         value="value1"/>
  </dictionarySample>
  <nameValueSample>
    <add key="key2" 
         value="value2" />
  </nameValueSample>
</configuration>
```

Above, I am defining two sections. One of type [`DictionarySectionHandler`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.dictionarysectionhandler(v=vs.71).aspx), and another of type [`NameValueSectionHandler`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.namevaluesectionhandler(v=vs.71).aspx).

As far as I can tell, these two Handlers are used in exactly the same way and result in identical configuration sections.

So, is there a difference, or can I use them interchangeably?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**TL;DR** `NameValueSectionHandler` is fine for `string`->`string` pairs in simple situations, but if you need your configuration to be efficient (particularly if you're going to be using `remove` repeatedly), use `DictionarySectionHandler`.

---

I dug into the source of these two classes ([NameValue](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/sys/system/configuration/NameValueSectionHandler.cs), [Dictionary](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/sys/system/configuration/DictionarySectionHandler.cs)), and found very little difference in implementation.

There are two things worth noting, though:

1. As the names of the handlers hint at, the primary difference is in the collections they use: `DictionarySectionHandler` stores its key/value pairs in a [`Hashtable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.hashtable(v=vs.110).aspx), whereas `NameValueSectionHandler` uses a [`NameValueCollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.namevaluecollection(v=vs.110).aspx).
2. In the `DictionarySectionHandler`, the `value` is not required and will default to an empty string if it is not provided, but `NameValueSectionHandler` requires the `value`.

As far as the differences between `Hashtable` and `NameValueCollection`, `NameValueCollection` can have duplicate keys, but `Hashtable` cannot. Additionally, `Hashtable` is pretty significantly more efficient in its implementation.

[This article on the MSDN Blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bclteam/archive/2006/09/05/741660.aspx) has some good information about `Hashtable` and `NameValueCollection`.

To summarize their findings, `Hashtable` is...

- 2.6x more efficient on lookup.
- 8.5x more efficient on add.
- an order of magnitude more efficient on remove.

They wrap up the article with some helpful information on when to use `NameValueCollection`:

> So you may be wondering when you’d want to use NameValueCollection. NameValueCollection only accepts keys and values that are Strings, so this is a very specialized collection. It’s useful in a situation in which you either need to associate multiple values with a key, or to do hash-based lookups as well as lookup by index (and hopefully not perform too many removes).
>
> However, if you need to store string key/value pairs and you don’t need to perform index-based lookups or associate multiple values with a key, you may prefer to use the generic Dictionary class. This has the same asymptotic behavior as Hashtable in all cases and furthermore avoids any costs due to boxing.